# I have two array of string. I want to compare both the array by lowerCasing each values in the array an return true/false if it matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am giving the example of two array.What is the best way to do this?Can we use some() function?

```
let firstArray = ['WickedWeed'];
let secondArray = ["wickedweed'];


//Output

true;
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: What is the output from two arrays with the exact same and two with different entries? Do ALL entries have to ne the same? Then use Array.every. Please elaborate or your question may be voted down and closed

Comment: Please update your question to include your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one element, then:

```
firstArray[0].toLowerCase() == secondArray[0].toLowerCase()
```

If there are multiple elements, then

```
firstArray.every((e,i)=>(secondArray[i].toLowerCase()==e.toLowerCase()))
```

If you don't need to match the index, then:

```
firstArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase()).every(e=>secondArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase()).includes(e))
```

```js
var firstArray=["abc","deF","zzz"];
var secondArray=["ABC","DEF","zZz"];

console.log(firstArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase()).every(e=>secondArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase()).includes(e)));
```

This can be computationally quite inefficient for long arrays, in which case it would be better to do it in two steps:

```js
var firstArray=["abc","deF","zzz"];
var secondArray=["ABC","DEF","zZz"];
var secondArrayl = secondArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase());
console.log(firstArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase()).every(e=>secondArrayl.includes(e)));
```

If you don't need to match every element:

```js
    var firstArray=["abc","deF","zzz"];
    var secondArray=["ABC"];
    var secondArrayl = secondArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase());
    console.log(firstArray.map(e=>e.toLowerCase()).some(e=>secondArrayl.includes(e)));
```

Comment: No there could be multiple elements

Comment: Do you only need to match the corresponding elements, ie. elements with the same index?

Comment: No. It should return true as soon as it finds the truthy value.Like how some() works

Comment: I gave you an up vote because, based on the little info given, you answered as best as possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use loadash  [docs for isequal](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

_.isEqual(array1, array2)

Comment: Is that case insensitive?

Comment: It might help to complete your answer a little so that users can see the input and output.